# Is there something like LeanEngine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth

After a while defining, what my actual problem is, I found [Lean-Engine](http://www.lean-engine.com/).

It is a library for GAE, which provides afaik all possible authentification methods, supported by GAE (and some features I don't need). The only thing that makes me worried about is, that it is 3 years old.
This means to me that:

1. This is not the way to go
2. It is out of date
3. since I had to search a lot, I guess no one is using it, which propably has reasons.

So my question:

Is there another library (in JAVA!) (a one up to date would be good) like that?

[Edit:]
There is another lib called [SimpleOauth](https://code.google.com/p/gae-simpleauth/), which is python only. Dunno, If I could combine that with my java endpoints. Still a year old... :/

Comment: could you elaborate on your exact problem?  There might be something that isn't a LeanEngine replacement but could still solve your issue.    You seem to be looking at LeanEngine for authorization purposes.  Could https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2  be helpful?

Comment: Correct me, but it seems to me like it is something were only users with Google accounts can use that.

Comment: Oauth2.0 is indeed for that.  You're trying to do your own authentification then?  This is a topic that seemed to be recurring and AFAIK no one provided a good answer as to what currently exists, so you might have to create your own for Java

Comment: Don't understand you. Indeed, it is for Google Accounts only? Or indeed, it's for any authentication?

Yes, I do want to do my own authentication.
Users should be able to register via whatever they want or register with username and email. With that information (whatever the user choose) he needs to be able to call GAE methods that are for registered users only.

Comment: Oauth 2.0 lets you sign in with a bunch of products (from Dropbox to facebook, gmail, windows live, whatnot).  I don't think (I'd have to double check) it is made for custom registration, but you can surely provide your own code for your own registered users and use Oauth 2.0 for the rest.

Comment: http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/  might help?  some other user was acking for the custom user authentication and this is something that came up, I didn't test it yet.  And looking at Oauth 2.0, it's not supporting custom registration AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

LeanEngine is not developed anymore (I'm the author). Also it's focus was not authentication only, but being a simple mobile-cloud solution (aka an open-source version of mobile clouds, e.g. Parse.com).

Oauth 2.0 is a standard, but it's pretty wide and differently implemented by different vendors. See [Pac4j](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j) for a cross-vendor multi-protocol authentication library. There is direct support for [different vendors](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j/tree/master/pac4j-oauth/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oauth/client) supporting OAuth. You can also easily add support for new vendor-specific OAuth logins.

Some time ago I added a patch to make it work on AppEngine.